# Ordered list in Django Model

Tags: django, models

I have a Django project where I want a Model to contain an ordered list of objects of another Model. If I've understood correctly, lists are usually done with foreign keys pointing from the contained objects to the containing object. But if I do it this way, will I be sure to maintain the order of the objects (the order in which I add them in the admin panel)? And what determines their order internally?

Also, if it is so that the elements with foreign keys are unordered, how would I go about making an ordered list in a Django Model?

Comment: 1st ask only 1 question

Comment: They will appear in the order you added them to your new model table, despite the order they have in their original table. So the new table will contain rows in the order you create them which contain a reference to another row in another table.

Comment: I have done something similar by adapting this Django snippet: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/998/

Answer (score 2):

You can specify in the Meta options on the model what field(s) to order by.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering

If you need to order by different fields in different queries, you can override the order_by on individual querysets.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

If you want to order them based on a timestamp (for instance when they were added to your database) then you would specify this in the Meta options.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can add a field that stores automatically the datetime when the object is created, with the auto_now_add attribute, like this example:

```
creation_date = models.DateTimeField('Date', auto_now_add=True)
```

Then, you can order in the DB by this field, with Meta attribute:

```
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('creation_date',)
```